# Unresponsive Scene During Scene Change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am working on a game with SpriteKit. I have finished my game, but wanted to add a main menu scene. I made two new files, "HomeScene.swift" and "HomeScene.sks". I was able to get the HomeScene to appear before the GameScene when I ran in the simulator, but it was not responsive to any touches, did not transition to the GameScene, or was affected by any code in my "HomeScene.swift" file.

Do I need to link the scene to the swift file somehow? Do I need to initialize the scene somehow?

Comment: in your HomeScene.sks file, you need to set the class to HomeScene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, thank you!